# Flutter app for IOS, is it possible to set IOS "Legacy Build System" without Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I'm going through the Firebase for Flutter Google Codelabs and came across the set "Legacy Build System" for IOS. I don't have a Mac and was hoping to delay the setup of a Mac VM. If I can set this flag then I can get codemagic to build my IOS app.

How to accomplish this without Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible to accomplish this without Xcode.

Both the new build system and the legacy build system for iOS use `xcodebuild` command line tool.

The difference is the flag `-UseModernBuildSystem=NO or YES`

Answer (score 0):

Launch Xcode, click File on the menu bar. A modal will appear where you can choose between legacy and the new build system[image]